# background image as per div width

Tags: css

I wanted to set div width 1309 pixels wide and the background image should fill the full width. So far I've tried this:

```
div{
    min-width: 1309px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("image-path") no-repeat -53px -9px;
    background-size: 109% 109%;
}
```

But when I resize the window it's hiding the background, but I wanted to implement the div width to be 1309px wide whatever we resize the window it should not be decreased but as far as I use background-size the div width is not 1309 pixels now when resizing (ie. if we resize the window it should have horizontal scroll bar as the width is 1309px).

There is no background-width. So, how can I implement?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2XATE/1/embedded/result/)

---

**Edit:**

I need to set background-position so that the background image would stay where I want.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fapud/1 check this one

Comment: I think that because of how jsfiddle shows embedded page. Scroll down to the end and I see the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: oh! yeah, it's amazed me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: cover` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2XATE/2/

```
div{
    min-width: 1309px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSw1qcO7NWH8LFMPPTvOwK7eK9GjRU9wNY8TZu2SWtjxKyMAXaMKF0gGRA") no-repeat -53px -9px;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    min-width: 1309px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSw1qcO7NWH8LFMPPTvOwK7eK9GjRU9wNY8TZu2SWtjxKyMAXaMKF0gGRA") no-repeat -53px -9px;
    background-size: 109% 109%;
}
```

Other than that, your code is working fine, i see scrollbar when i resize the window.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fapud/3)

Comment: Then, your code was working fine before itself. No modifications required

Comment: no but not scrolling .... To say, the background image is not full width as the div width...

Comment: Am unable to reproduce that @C-link when i resize window, the background is covering full width